# How to corresponding the GCP components or how to understand?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm studying how to use GCP, especially focus on the Big Data and analytic functions, I'm not quite sure about their functionality. I did some mapping to understand these components. Could you help to check out my understanding?

- Cloud Pub/Sub: Apache Kafka
- Cloud Dataproc: Apache Hadoop, Spark
- GCS: HDFS compatible
- Cloud Dataflow: Apache Beam, Flink
- Datastore: MongoDB
- BigQuery: Teradata
- BigTable: HBase
- Memorystore: Redis
- Cloud SQL: MySQL, PostgreSQL
- Cloud Composer: Informatica
- Cloud Data Studio: Tableau
- Cloud Datalab: Jupyter notebook

Comment: You are pretty close. However, I would not worry about the comparision unless you already know the non Google products well. GCP has its own style of delivering services, management interfaces and security features. Focus on the basics of GCP before you start thinking about Big Data services.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally sure what you want to know, your understanding of the GCP products is not far off, but if you are studiying GCP and want to understand them better, you can take a look at the [Google Cloud developer's cheat sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gregsramblings/google-cloud-4-words/master/Poster-medres.png). It has a brief explanation of all the products inside GCP.

*Link to the [GitHub of the cheat sheet](https://github.com/gregsramblings/google-cloud-4-words)*

Comment: Thank you , this cheat sheet is very helpful.